# The boundary between polycrystalline and crystalline

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

My current understanding of solid crystalline-like materials (please correct me if I'm wrong!) is that it is a continuum in terms of crystallinity, from amorphous (basically no periodicity) to single crystals (complete periodicity), with ["polycrystalline"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycrystalline) pretty much covering everything in the middle, like the wiki article shows.

So my question is, what should you expect from a polycrystal in terms of properties you know about a single crystal of the same material, such as dispersion relation, band structure, etc?

Obviously, it's a continuum, so you should expect a polycrystal that's *almost* a single crystal (maybe like, a single crystal split in two, and put back together the tiniest bit off) to behave pretty damn similar to a single crystal. It seems like each single crystallite in a polycrystal should act as a tiny crystal with the band structure of a perfect crystal.

But what do you do as the grains get smaller? Is there some way to predict how close to a single crystal you should expect the polycrystal to behave, given its average and variance of grain sizes? As the grains get smaller, it seems like you should expect the thin layers of amorphous solid holding the crystallites together to be more and more important.

In fact, is there any sort of formalism for working with amorphous solids?

Thanks!

Comment: The naivest thing to say is that if the size of the grains is much larger than the Fermi wavelength, then the boundaries just look like some kind of disorder and so your system looks metallic, if it doesn't localize. But maybe there is something more subtle, I don't know.

Comment: There is another thing - since the grain boundary are connected, they from a network which permeates the solid. So if the boundaries conduct heat, let's say, better than the bulk, the thermal conductivity will be determined by the boundaries. This also happens with some kinds of spontaneous order, where the domains are insulating but the boundaries between the domains carry gapless excitations.